# Format column throw exception when this column contains null value

Tags: ms-access, ucanaccess

I have a table that naming MVorders. it contains a column(orderdate) that type is date/time, and it's contains null value, then format column throw exception.

e.g. sql : `SELECT format(MVorders.orderdate, "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00") FROM MVorders`

**Env:** UCanAccess 4.0.4.

Thanks!

**Reference:**

[image: Table struct]

[image: Table data]

Answer (score 0):

SELECT IIF(ISNULL(orderdate), '', Format(orderdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00')) AS FormattedOrderDate FROM MVorders

Comment: this is error. reference:
>  IIf always evaluates both truepart and falsepart, even though it returns only one of them. Because of this, you should watch for undesirable side effects. For example, if evaluating falsepart results in a division by zero error, an error occurs even if expr is True.

Comment: [IIF Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3)

Comment: This seems to be just a null value judgment lack for ucanaccess.

Comment: Modify to `Format(Nz(orderdate,Date()), 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00')`. It may be enough to just use `Format(Nz(orderdate), 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00')` too.

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered a known deficiency in the UCanAccess implementation of the `FORMAT` function. It has been reported to the UCanAccess development team.